# Renaming multiple folders via command prompt

Tags: batch-file, command, windows-10, prompt

So I am trying to write a batch script to rename multiple folders. I would like to do something like below: Rename all folders under the "Workspace" folder by adding up the number in the filename by 1.

For example, rename:

```
Workspace/A0084
Workspace/A0085
Workspace/A0086
```

to:

```
Workspace/A0085
Workspace/A0086
Workspace/A0087
```

Is this possible? (Adding 1 from the folder name)

Comment: @user202729 Hi, I am sorry. I am not familiar with this platform, and I have only used a several times. Is there any standards in asking questions I have missed out? Isn't it commending or giving 'up' to answers is consider the way of thanking ones' effort? Anyway, I am thinking to do the following, but not sure if it will work:

1. Removing A00 from all the folders.
2. Get the filename and +1 from there
3. Add back the A00 prefix

Comment: Also... why using Batch and not some other programming language (Python, for example)?

Comment: @user202729 I have never deal with Phyton before, and I knew batch file can do and would be easier to create one i.e.: put in the codes in notepad and save as batch file. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: ... Yes, it doesn't require any dependency. Now, try to write the code yourself, and if you have any problem with the code, come back here with a specific question. Don't ask us where is the documentation, type `help` into the command line gives you most of the necessary contents.

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

if exist Workspace\A9999\. (
  rd /S /Q Workspace\A9999 >NUL 2>&1
)
for /L %%x in (9999, -1, 1) do (
  set NUM=000%%x
  set NEW_SUB=A!NUM:-4!
  if exist Workspace\!NEW_SUB!\. (
    ren Workspace\!NEW_SUB!\ Workspace\!OLD_SUB! >NUL 2>&1
  )
  set OLD_SUB=!NEW_SUB!
)
```

reinhard -:)